# How can I have a moment object but not have access to any of the methods?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a moment object(e.g., temp1). I verify that it is a moment with `moment.isMoment(temp1);`, which returns `true`.

When I use any of the methods on the moment object, I get the TypeError `temp1[method] is not a function`.

[image: valid moment with no access to methods]

[image: the moment object with methods]

Comment: That looks interesting, can you post a snippet illustrating the problem?

Comment: Something has replaced all the methods with objects. It should be `isValid: ƒ {}`

Comment: Actually, I'd expect all these methods to be inherited from the prototype, not be visible in each object. These local properties are overriding the inherited methods.

Comment: Interesting! Okay. I have no idea how that's happening but that gives me a good place to start. Thanks